# Website to apply some visual style to a vector image (SVG, etc)

Tags: vector, svg, automation, style, raster

Question: If I have a vector path (let's say it's an SVG), what's a website I can send it to and get various "styles" in return?

What I mean by "style" is just: change the colors of the vector paths around randomly or based on some palette, and apply some kind of visual effects... and for my purposes, it's perfectly fine if the result is a raster, so therefore whatever "visual effects" are applied could be raster effects.

...

My specific purpose (irrelevant to OP): I have a client who wants to have lots of real-life QR codes in his store, and I just want to make them less of eyesores.  There are a few websites around that generate styled QR codes, but not much variety.  So I'm looking for sites that can take my already-generated QR codes as vector paths and just stylize them for me; the more styles the better, and "random" styling is fine by me since I can just choose whichever results look good to my eye. However, QR codes are NOT on-topic for this OP; I'm aware that many "visual stylings" would make the codes unreadable by a scanner, but then again, many can be read just fine.

Comment: I don't know if any site that would do this, though I'm sure someone could write an Inkscape extension that does this.

Answer (score 0):

It is is currently not possible to modify SVG styles in the browser, however this is set to change soon, once the [SVG2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVGParamPrimer-20090616/) is finalized and adopted by vendors. However W3 use a [polyfill script](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVGParamPrimer-20090616/param.js) on the aforementioned article to emulate the effect

Answer (score 0):

If its just applying styles to an SVG element/object, you can do that using CSS. Check out this totorial at [smashingmagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/03/styling-and-animating-svgs-with-css/). Gives a complete overview on SVG styling using CSS.